# Concatenate values from a table then update a field in a different table with those values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I need to populate a field in Table1 with concatenated data from Table2 based on the AuthorIDs in Table 1. The IDs in table 1 are a string separated by a ;. for example '234;242;54'

I found a function that will turn CSV into a table, I can then use those values to grab the GUIDs associated with those IDs and concatenate them

```
SELECT TOP 100 *,
  stuff((
        select ';' + convert(varchar(200),AuthorGuid)
        from 
            (select t.AuthorGuid
            from Table2 t
            where t.AuthorID in (select * from dbo.CSVToTable(REPLACE(w.Authors,';',',')))
            ) auths
        for xml path('')), 1, 1, '') as AuthorGUIDStemp
  FROM Table1 w
```

The above query puts the GUIDS in a temporary field in Table1 but I need to update Table1

```
update Table1 w set AuthorGUIDs = 
    stuff((
        select ';' + convert(varchar(200),AuthorGuid)
        from 
            (select t.AuthorGuid
            from Table2 t
            where t.AuthorID in (select * from dbo.CSVToTable(REPLACE(Authors,';',',')))
            ) auths
        for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
```

This does not work to update the field & throws errors.

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
> Incorrect syntax near 'w'.
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 23
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'for'.

How do I make this update work?

Comment: What is the error your getting? You would probably be better off using `UPDATE...FROM...` Syntax.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your update syntax may be off.  I believe you're attempting to update AuthorGuids with an type XML.

Try this assuming the results you want are text:

```
 UPDATE  w
  SET   AuthorGUIDs = STUFF((   SELECT  ';' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(200), AuthorGuid)
                                  FROM
                                    (   SELECT  t.AuthorGuid
                                          FROM  Table2 t
                                          WHERE t.AuthorID IN(SELECT    * FROM  dbo.CSVToTable(REPLACE(Authors, ';', ',')) ))auths
                                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max'), 1, 1, '')

  FROM  Table1 w
```

Comment: are you trying the whole command?  through  "FROM Table1 W" ?  Sorry not being snarky if you understand the alias on the update. if so and it's still failing idk.  It passes my syntax check but since I don't have the actual tables best I can do.